# Workflow and Tooling for Production Use of Angular's Internationalisation

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

Angular's internationalisation solution seems to still be in development. At the same time, it is now officially listed in the documentation and therefore I would assume it is now ready for use in production applications.

What I can't figure out though is what workflow and tooling could be used with this solution in a commercial setting.

The workflow makes some sense to me. A developer will develop the application, generate the source strings for translations, and generate a file which translators can load into a program to translate the strings with minimum technical expertise. To generate the file one uses the extractor (xi18n) to get a non-translated template XLIFF, copies this for each language, and the translator uses a XLIFF editor to update each language from the template as changes occur to it due to later extractions and changes in source strings. This would be similar to the Gettext approach. Is this the appropriate strategy for Angular too, or are the translation files updated from the template XLIFF in some other way with Angular?

The larger problem for me though is how Angular pieces the XLIFF file together. Unfortunately the way Angular brings XLIFF 1.2 and ICU together seems pretty complex and I have yet to find a tool that can properly handle this. Angular seems to use a XLIFF placeholder in the translation unit, using simply the text "ICU" as the ID and an ICU-like pattern in equiv-text. This is then somehow matched to another translation unit containing a random ID and the full ICU expression. Interpolation is also handled using a placeholder with ID "INTERPOLATION" and the variable in the equiv-text.

Not only is it hard to figure out exactly what Angular is doing internally to do the matching of ICU expression, but the result of all of this in a XLIFF editor is difficult for even me, a developer, to understand, let alone a translator. In the screenshot an example of the ICU and interpolation can be seen using the Virtaal XLIFF editor. This is produced out of the translation source string below, extracted to the XLIFF below it. You can't really do much at all with the placeholders and you can't see a connection between the VAR_PLURAL ICU translation and the translation in which it is used. I've looked at other editors and they seem to have similar problems.

[image: Virtaal]

Angular Template:

```
<ng-container i18n>Example with ICU {randomNumber, plural, =1 {expression} other {expressions}}: {{randomDecimal}}</ng-container>
```

XLIFF:

```
  <trans-unit id="698dc3ea0590e8f5f533d296e91d012993eb9b36" datatype="html">
    <source>Example with ICU <x id="ICU" equiv-text="{randomNumber, plural, =1 {...} other {...}}"/>: <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{randomDecimal}}"/></source>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">OMITTED</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
    </context-group>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="e3f60ad6a9d907d30e2c51244085d3084d326cbe" datatype="html">
    <source>{VAR_PLURAL, plural, =1 {expression} other {expressions} }</source>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">OMITTED</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
    </context-group>
  </trans-unit>
```

What tooling do people usually use with Angular applications intended for production use to get around these problems so that the translation file actually makes sense to the translator? I've read that a lot of people edit the files by hand, but I don't think that would be translator-friendly at all.

Comment: Requests for off site resources like tooling are off topic here, see the [help].

Comment: From my understanding, questions about tooling are off-topic because they get opinionated answers. Would that still be an issue if I'm looking for whether any tooling specific to this problem exists at all?

Comment: Hi @BradenWalters did you ever figure out a decent workflow for this?  I'm struggling with the same issues you describe on Angular 10

Comment: Unfortunately no. My problem was solved when I stopped working on that Angular project. I currently am not using Angular anymore, but I would use a third-party internationalisation tool if I did. Due to this problem (among others), I've lost confidence in the built-in internationalisation library in Angular.